# Interpretation of spatial lag models

Tags: regression, interpretation, autocorrelation

I have estimated a linear regression model via R's `spdep` package (`lagsarlm` function), in which spatial auto-correlation was controlled for by an IDW matrix. I wonder whether the interpretation of model results is different from that of OLS models. For example, if a coefficient is 0.2, can I interpret it as: one unit increase in IV leads to 0.2 unit increase in DV?

Answer (score 2):

yes, but you should also look at the direct and indirect effects of the predictors using the impacts() function within the package

Comment: Thank you, Corey! I wonder if there is an example showing the use impacts() function in the package. Are you aware of any?

Comment: the help file does: ?impacts will get you started, if you're looking for rules of thumb (i'm not a big fan), I doubt there are any. The best description i've seen is in the second edition of Applied Spatial Data analysis in R by Bivand et al, section 9.4, it goes through it pretty well